# Fatal error TLS client credential

Tags: windows, ssl, wireshark

I have disabled SSLv3, TLS1.0 and 1.1 on a Windows 10 domain joined laptop, I also disabled triple DES 168 and MD5 to comply with our PCI scans and since then the system logs are full of the same error:
A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013.

I found some articles about that error, one of which shows how to enable TLS1.2 for the Net framework v.4 which I followed but it didn't help at all.

So I reenabled all protocols on the client side one by one and it seems the error stops when I enable SSLv3.

I have installed Wireshark in hope to see more info, notably by looking at Client Hello and Server Hello but I am getting way too much output.

How would you go about finding what specifically causes these errors?

Comment: What server(s) are you connecting to?

Comment: None in particular, there is some behind the scene connections that cause these issues which is why I thought Wireshark could help find out.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121859/a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-a-tls-client-credential-the-internal-erro

Comment: @JozefIzso: It's not.